# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED with WPBakery Visual Composer

Tags: google-chrome

On Chrome I have "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED" error messages related to jQuery plugin "prettyphoto" which is itself, on my site, called by plugin "Visual Composer" by WPBakery.

Any idea how to fix that?

[image]